# I am publishing Yaw. I am getting continuous rotation along Z axis

Tags: ros2, imu

I am reading and publishing Yaw from mpu6050.but i am seeing continuous rotation along Z axis. I am using Rviz to visualize MPU data. although when I actually rotate the sensor I get rotation.
below is my ros2 node to publish imu/data

```
     #!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import smbus
import struct
import rclpy
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import Temperature, Imu
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster
from tf2_geometry_msgs import TransformStamped
import tf2_ros
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster
from tf2_geometry_msgs import tf2_geometry_msgs
import numpy as np
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion, Vector3  
import smbus
from time import sleep
import math
yaw = 0  # Add this line to initialize yaw
PWR_MGMT_1 = 0x6b

ACCEL_CONFIG = 0x1C
ACCEL_XOUT_H = 0x3B
ACCEL_XOUT_L = 0x3C
ACCEL_YOUT_H = 0x3D
ACCEL_YOUT_L = 0x3E
ACCEL_ZOUT_H = 0x3F
ACCEL_ZOUT_L = 0x40

GYRO_CONFIG = 0x1B
GYRO_XOUT_H = 0x43
GYRO_XOUT_L = 0x44
GYRO_YOUT_H = 0x45
GYRO_YOUT_L = 0x46
GYRO_ZOUT_H = 0x47
GYRO_ZOUT_L = 0x48

TEMP_H = 0x41
TEMP_L = 0x42

ADDR = None
bus = None
IMU_FRAME = None
dt=0.001
alpha = 0.5  # Complementary filter constant (adjust as needed)

def read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(ADDR, adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(ADDR, adr+1)
    val = (high << 8) + low
    return val

def read_word_2c(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

def publish_temp(timer_event=None):
    temp_msg = Temperature()
    temp_msg.header.frame_id = IMU_FRAME
    temp_msg.temperature = read_word_2c(TEMP_H)/340.0 + 36.53
    temp_msg.header.stamp = rclpy.time.Time(seconds=time.time()).to_msg()
    temp_pub.publish(temp_msg)

def euler_to_quaternion(roll, pitch, yaw):
    cy = math.cos(yaw * 0.5)
    sy = math.sin(yaw * 0.5)
    cr = math.cos(roll * 0.5)
    sr = math.sin(roll * 0.5)
    cp = math.cos(pitch * 0.5)
    sp = math.sin(pitch * 0.5)

    w = cy * cr * cp + sy * sr * sp
    x = cy * sr * cp - sy * cr * sp
    y = cy * cr * sp + sy * sr * cp
    z = sy * cr * cp - cy * sr * sp

    return Quaternion(x=x, y=y, z=z, w=w)


def update_orientation(acceleration, gyro_rate):
    global roll, pitch, yaw

    # Compute pitch and roll from accelerometer data
    accel_pitch = math.atan2(acceleration[1], 
    math.sqrt(acceleration[0]**2 + acceleration[2]**2))
    accel_roll = math.atan2(-acceleration[0], acceleration[2])

    # Integrate gyro data to update yaw
    global yaw
    yaw += gyro_rate[2] * dt  # Assuming gyro_rate is a tuple (gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z)

    # Initialize roll and pitch if they are not defined yet
    if 'roll' not in globals():
        roll = 0.0
    if 'pitch' not in globals():
        pitch = 0.0

    # Apply complementary filter to combine accelerometer and gyro data
    pitch = alpha * (pitch + gyro_rate[1] * dt) + (1 - alpha) * accel_pitch
    roll = alpha * (roll + gyro_rate[0] * dt) + (1 - alpha) * accel_roll

    return roll, pitch, yaw




def publish_imu(timer_event=None):
    global yaw  
    imu_msg = Imu()
    imu_msg.header.frame_id = IMU_FRAME

    # Read the acceleration vals
    accel_x = read_word_2c(ACCEL_XOUT_H) / 16384.0
    accel_y = read_word_2c(ACCEL_YOUT_H) / 16384.0
    accel_z = read_word_2c(ACCEL_ZOUT_H) / 16384.0

    # Calculate a quaternion representing the orientation
    accel = accel_x, accel_y, accel_z
    ref = np.array([0, 0, 1])
    acceln = accel / np.linalg.norm(accel)
    angle = np.linalg.norm(accel) * 0.1  # Scale the angle to make it visually better
    axis = accel / np.linalg.norm(accel)
    orientation = np.array([axis[0] * np.sin(angle / 2.0), axis[1] * np.sin(angle / 2.0), axis[2] * np.sin(angle / 2.0), np.cos(angle / 2.0)])
    accel = np.array([accel_x, accel_y, accel_z])


    # Read the gyro vals
    gyro_x = read_word_2c(GYRO_XOUT_H) / 131.0
    gyro_y = read_word_2c(GYRO_YOUT_H) / 131.0
    gyro_z = read_word_2c(GYRO_ZOUT_H) / 131.0

    #roll, pitch, yaw = update_orientation(Vector3(accel_x, accel_y, accel_z), Vector3(gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z))
    # Call update_orientation with tuples
    roll, pitch, yaw = update_orientation((accel_x, accel_y, accel_z), (gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z))





    yaw += gyro_z * 0.02  # dt is the time elapsed between readings
    # Calculate quaternion from yaw
    quaternion = euler_to_quaternion(roll, pitch, yaw)

    # Load up the IMU message
    o = imu_msg.orientation
    o.x, o.y, o.z, o.w = orientation

    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = accel_x * 9.8
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = accel_y * 9.8
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = accel_z * 9.8

    imu_msg.angular_velocity.x = gyro_x * 0.0174
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = gyro_y * 0.0174
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = gyro_z * 0.0174
    imu_msg.orientation = quaternion

    imu_msg.header.stamp = rclpy.time.Time(seconds=time.time()).to_msg()
    print(imu_msg)

    imu_pub.publish(imu_msg)


    
def main():
    global bus, ADDR, IMU_FRAME, temp_pub, imu_pub

    rclpy.init()
    node = rclpy.create_node('imu_node')


    STATIC_BUS = 1  # Set to the desired bus value
    STATIC_ADDR = 0x68  # Set to the desired I2C address value

    bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
    ADDR = 0x68
    IMU_FRAME = 'imu_frame'
    
    bus.write_byte_data(ADDR, PWR_MGMT_1, 0)

    temp_pub = node.create_publisher(Temperature, 'temperature', 10)
    imu_pub = node.create_publisher(Imu, 'imu/data_raw', 10)
    
    temp_timer = node.create_timer(10, publish_temp)
    imu_timer = node.create_timer(0.02, publish_imu)

    rclpy.spin(node)

    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you calculate the `yaw += gyro_z * 0.02` separately if you already calculated yaw in your update_orientation function? However, this does not seem to be the issue as you are using the correct `gyro_z` value. What do you expect at the end? When you update the yaw value, you will see the changes along the Z-axis. What is the problem with the result?

Comment: it keeps rotating in clockwise along z even if the sensor is steady.

Answer (score 0):

Per [ROS Rep 103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html), we use the right-hand rule as our frame convention. So seeing yaw movement correspond to rotation about the Z is correct. If you mean 'continuous' as in "it moves even when I don't tell it it's moving", you're seeing sensor drift, which is an unfortunate fact of sensors: they have error, and when you add up values, that error accumulates.

Answer (score 0):

The IMU sensors include 6 sensors, one gyroscope and accelerometer per each axis. Unfortunately, both are not only noisy (like all sensors) but also have biases. Bias is an offset which is non-constant (but its dynamics is very slow).
This is most probably what you are reading from your sensor.

Depending on your application, it can be enough if you leave the sensor static for some seconds. Averaging you can extract the biases (take into account the gravity for accelerometers) at current time. This callibration should work for some seconds or minutes (depending on the sensor).

If you need more time/accuracy, another source of information will be required to track these biases. This is the case of Visual Inertial Odometry methods or SLAM using IMU.